# How to use if condition when reading a column in pandas

Tags: pandas

I am reading two columns in my tsv file and add it to a dataframe as follows.

```
input_data = pd.read_csv( input_file, header=0, delimiter="\t", quoting=3 )
L= input_data["title"] + '. ' + input_data["description"]
```

However, some of my titles have already got a fullstop `.`, that makes the line as `some title here.. description here`.

Therefore, I thought to add a if statement to see if the title string has a fullstop at the end. If yes, avoid adding another fullstop. If no, add the fullstop.

i.e.

```
if title[-1] == '.':
    #do not add a fullstop before appending the fullstop
else:
    #add the fullstop
```

I am wondering if it is possible to do it using pandas. I am happy to provide any details if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
# first remove full stop
input_data['title'] = input_data['title'].str.replace('.','')

# now join with full stop
L= input_data["title"] + '. ' + input_data["description"]
```